# How do I change this code to work with asynchronous sockets

Tags: javascript, sockets, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox add-on with Jetpack and I need to implement a communication between the add-on and a server written in Java. The communication must be opened when the add-on starts and then every time that the add-on needs it, it makes a request to the server. But it must be **Synchronous** because it needs the server response in order to continue executing.

I've been looking for examples of synchronous sockets in javascript but I didn't get results. May be it can be done by asynchronous code, but I don't know how to.

EDIT: Here is the code of my add-on (using [jetpack-net](https://github.com/Gozala/jetpack-net) library):

```
var net = require('net');

var Server = function() {

    this.socket = net.createConnection(6666, 'localhost');      
    this.socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.replace(/\n/gm," "));
    }).on('connect', function() {
        //console.log('Socket connected.');         
    }).on('end', function() {
        //console.log('Connection finished.');
    });

    this.findCategory = function(query) {
        this.socket.write(query + "\n");
    }

}

exports.main = function() {

    var gs = new Server();              
    processResult(gs.findCategory('Bye'));

};
```

Comment: What's wrong with routing all control flow through a callback?

Comment: This isn't an *answer*, so I'll post it as a comment: 1. I don't *think* there's any way to do synchronous sockets in JavaScript on a browser, even Firefox. 2. You should be able to do it with *asynchronous* sockets via the [Web Sockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) API, which [Firefox supports](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets).

Comment: Show us your code and turn your question into: "How do I make this work with asynchronous sockets?"

Comment: I agree with the other commenters, your question shouldn't be "how do I make sockets work synchronously" but rather "how do I change my code to work with asynchronous sockets". Synchronous actions should be avoided in Firefox extensions as much as possible.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm sorry but I'm new on stackoverflow and I don't know how to edit the post.

@T.J.Crowder: But the problem is that I don't know how to do it with asynchronous sockets. I need to process all values that the server responses and I've got nothing to do until then.

Comment: @user1336939: *"I don't know how to edit the post"* Click the "edit" link under the question (just under the tags). *"But it must be Synchronous because it needs the server response in order to continue executing."* You don't need it to be synchronous to do that, you just have to pass in a callback function. That's how async stuff works: You issue a "go get the data" call and pass a callback function in; when the data is received, the browser will call your callback function. Think of callbacks as being like event handlers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I've already worked with async stuff in other functions of the add-on. And I've tried passing a callback function but it didn't work to me. I'll try again and tell you. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: You really need to bite the bullet and learn to love async and event-driven programming. Please see this ( excellent ) post for an illustration of how to do this: http://wekeroad.com/2012/04/05/cleaning-up-deep-callback-nesting-with-nodes-eventemitter/